# Connecting 2 graphs according to NearestNeighbor and degree distribution

Tags: graphs-and-networks, random-process

### Context and example:

Suppose we have 2 graphs $g_1,g_2$ that we connect together by introducing edges between each node of $g_1$ and its corresponding nearest neighbors within the second graph $g_2.$ This process does not perturb the edgelists of the original graphs (i.e., the edges that defined e.g. $g_1$ are not removed or rewired). The nearest neighbor is defined here according to the Euclidean distance between the nodes. In a [previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/204467/52181), [halmir](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/590/halmir) provided a very neat solution to this problem by using the [`NearestNeighborGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph.html) function in order to introduce the new edges, here's an example:

The two graphs before connecting them with one another:

```
SeedRandom[124]
g1 = RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[30, 0.3, 2], 
   VertexStyle -> Green];

SeedRandom[150]
g2 = IndexGraph[
   RandomGraph[SpatialGraphDistribution[30, 0.3, 2], 
    VertexStyle -> Red], 31];
```

The vertex coordinates of the embedding and our distance function:

```
vcoord1 = {##, 0} & @@@ GraphEmbedding[g1];
vcoord2 = {##, .4} & @@@ GraphEmbedding[g2];

dist[{_, _, x_}, {_, _, x_}] := 100
dist[x_, y_] := EuclideanDistance[x, y]
```

And the newly introduced edges between `g1,g2`:

```
wire = EdgeList[
   IndexGraph[
    NearestNeighborGraph[Join[vcoord1, vcoord2], 2, 
     DistanceFunction -> dist, DirectedEdges -> False]]];
```

The `2` argument in the above means: each node is connected to `2` nearest neighbors.

And visualised with the `g1` nodes colored red and `g2` colored green:

```
Graph3D[Range[60], Join[EdgeList[g1], EdgeList[g2], wire], 
 VertexCoordinates -> Join[vcoord1, vcoord2], 
 VertexStyle -> 
  Join[Thread[Range[30] -> Green], Thread[Range[31, 60] -> Red]]]
```

[image]

---

### Question

What I am trying to figure out is, how to sample/define `wire` in the above, that is the edges introduced between the two graphs, such that a target degree distribution is obtained? In other words, if we were to treat the newly introduced edges as a graph by itself, then it has a corresponding degree distribution, e.g. in the above example that is given by the following distribution:

```
Histogram[VertexDegree[wire], {1}, "Probability", 
 AxesLabel -> {"degree", "probability"}]
```

[image]

We could randomly sample edges from the list `wire` with a probability `p`:

```
wiresampled = RandomSample[wire, Ceiling[Length@wire*p]];
```

but this doesn't allow us to sample a desired degree distribution/sequence from `wire`, which might for example be uniform (all degrees constant) or Poisson distributed.

On the one hand, using functions such as [`IGRewire`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igrewire) from the [`IGraph/M`](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/igraphm-a-mathematica-interface-for-igraph.html) package is not obvious either, as the rewiring would ignore the nearest neighbor requirement. Moreover, as far as I know, the reverse graph generation functions such as [`IGRealizeDegreeSequence`](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#igrealizedegreesequence) do not allow for nearest-neighbor specifications. On the other hand, the built-in [`DegreeGraphDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DegreeGraphDistribution.html) cannot be used with the function [`NearestNeighborGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NearestNeighborGraph.html), or at least I don't see how the two can be married in the above scheme.

- In short then, is there a way we could use the `NearestNeighborGraph` routine while also obtaining a desired degree distribution for the newly introduced edges (between `g1,g2`)? In other words, how can we sample the nearest neighbor edges added between `g1` and `g2` according to a degree distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ClearAll[bipartiteWire]
bipartiteWire[ga_Graph, gb_Graph, d1_, d2_] := 
  Module[{am = Array[\[FormalA], VertexCount /@ {ga, gb}], 
       dm = Join @@ DistanceMatrix @@ (GraphEmbedding /@ {ga, gb})}, 
   NMinimize[{dm.(Join @@ am), 
      And @@ Join[Thread[Total[am] == d2], 
        Thread[Total[am, {2}] == d1], 
        Thread[0 <= Join @@ am <= 1],
        {Element[Join@@am, Integers]}]}, 
     Join @@ am][[2]] // 
   Cases[HoldPattern[\[FormalA][i_, j_] -> 1] :> UndirectedEdge[i, VertexCount[ga] + j]]]
```

***Examples:***

Constant degree sequences:

```
vd1 = ConstantArray[2, VertexCount[g1]];
vd2 = ConstantArray[2, VertexCount[g2]];

wire2 = bipartiteWire[g1, g2, vd1, vd2];

Tally[VertexDegree @ wire2]
```

> {{2, 60}}

```
Graph3D[Range[60], Join[EdgeList[g1], EdgeList[g2], wire2], 
 VertexCoordinates -> Join[vcoord1, vcoord2], 
 VertexStyle -> Join[Thread[Range[30] -> Green], Thread[Range[31, 60] -> Red]]]
```

[image]

```
Tally[VertexDegree @
  bipartiteWire[g1, g2, ConstantArray[3, VertexCount[g1]], 
   ConstantArray[3, VertexCount[g2]]]]
```

> {{3, 60}}

Examples with a random degree sequences:

```
SeedRandom[1]
rvd1 = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, VertexCount[g1]];
SortBy[First] @ Tally @ rvd1
```

> {{1, 7}, {2, 5}, {3, 4}, {4, 6}, {5, 8}}

```
rvd2 = RandomSample[rvd1];

SortBy[First] @ Tally[VertexDegree @ bipartiteWire[g1, g2, rvd1, rvd2]]
```

> {{1, 14}, {2, 10}, {3, 8}, {4, 12}, {5, 16}}

```
SeedRandom[123]
rvd1 = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, VertexCount[g1]];
SortBy[First] @ Tally @ rvd1
```

> {{1, 6}, {2, 8}, {3, 6}, {4, 3}, {5, 7}}

```
rvd2 = RandomSample @RandomChoice[IntegerPartitions[Total@rvd1, {30}, Range[5]]];
SortBy[First] @ Tally @ rvd2
```

> {{1, 1}, {2, 13}, {3, 7}, {4, 6}, {5, 3}}

```
SortBy[First] @ Tally[VertexDegree @ bipartiteWire[g1, g2, rvd1, rvd2]]
```

> {{1, 7}, {2, 21}, {3, 13}, {4, 9}, {5, 10}}

Comment: @user929304, this is a straightforward constrained minimization formulation forcing vertex degrees to match the input degree sequences and minimizing the total distance between connected vertices. The error message may be due previously defined `a`.  See if changing ` a` to `\[FormalA` fixes the issue.

Comment: @user929304, don't know how `\[DoubleStruckCapitalZ]` got into your code, but it should be replaced with `Integers`.

Comment: Same it's really puzzling, I have literally copied your code for the module after which I define `g1` and `g2` exactly like in my post, then `vd1, vd2` are assigned as you have and finally I evaluate `wire2 = bipartiteWire[g1, g2, vd1, vd2];
Tally[VertexDegree@wire2]` which leads to the said error. Could you please kindly re-test the posted code on your end again?

Comment: @user929304, please try the new version. The original code works without issue in version 11.3.0 (Windows 10). Looks like there has been some update to `NMinimize`  in version 12.0 so i got the same error as you did in version 12.0 (Wolfram Cloud). The updated version works in version 12.0 and version 11.3.

Comment: Indeed that has resolved the problem, well spotted and thank you very much! I can now test the approach for bigger graphs and different degree dists, I'll get back to you asap regarding the results!

Comment: (...) In other words, lets take the Poisson which is of particular interest in my case, then our desired degree sequence is ‘seq = RandomVariate[PoissonDistribution[3],60];’ that is, we want ‘Histogram[VertexDegree[bipartiteWire[g1,g2, vd1, vd2]], {1}, “Probability”]’ to be as close to the Histogram of ‘seq’ as possible. But the problem is, we only know ‘seq’ as input, and not the individual degree sequences ‘vd1,vd2’, and I dont know how to generate these such that bipartiteWire results in the target ‘seq’. Any follow-up hints on either of these questions would be much much appreciated!

Comment: @user929304, since every edge in `wire` should connect a vertex of `g1` to a vertex of `g2` we cannot have an arbitrary 60-vector  `seq` as input degree sequence. If we partition  `seq` into two 30-vectors corresponding to the vertices from `g1` and `g2` (using, say, the labeling convention that the first 30 correspond to vertices from `g1` and the last 30 to vertices from `g2`) then _**the sum of the first 30 degrees and the sum of the last 30 degrees should be equal**_. (This is probably the reason why `NMinimize` is unable to find a solution -- because there is no feasible solution). ...

Comment: With an input vector `seq` that satisfies this condition  the histograms of `seq` and the `NMinimize` output will be identical.  Re exploiting  `NearestNeighborGraph` I cannot think of any way to use `NearestNeighborGraph` with constraints on the degree sequence.

Comment: After discussing with ciao [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216003/52181), pertaining to our discussion of composing the individual degree sequences to be used in `bipartiteWire`, it seems generally, it is highly improbable to find sequences that satisfy the desired criteria of the sum, e.g. as soon as the number of nodes between the  graphs we're trying to connect together becomes too large. In hindsight, can you imagine a way that would allow us to approximate our above bipartite wiring approach? in order to relax the dependency of `NMinimize` on finding *exact* solutions. (..)

Comment: (...) In other words, our wiring matching roughly the desired deg. dist. would be acceptable too. Of course, we'd have to define clearly what we mean by *rough*, e.g. it can be based on the distance of the obtained dist, w.r.t to the target one, for which we introduce a threshold. Anyhow, I might be overcomplicating it again :/, definitely look forward to your ideas on this. Thanks for any follow-up input.

Comment: @user929304, haven't tried the method for large inputs. Re "matching roughly the desired degree", maybe you can try changing the constraints replacing `Thread[Total[am] == d2]` with `Thread[Max[0,d2- tol] <=Total[am] <= d2 +tol]` and `Thread[Total[am, {2} ] == d2]` with `Thread[Max[0,d1- tol] <=Total[am, {2}] <= d1 +tol]` with tolerance `tol` of your choice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. That's a cool idea, I ve tried it on a few cases but `NMinimize` cannot find solutions even with very small `tol` values (such as 0,1,2...).

Comment: Another idea :) Could we maybe use the `KolmogorovSmirnovTest[data,dist]` test to make the approximation? (i.e. the test would be part of the minimization, and above a certain value we'd deem *acceptable*), or I am going a bit off-sides with this? :/